California Zephyr from Colorado
I am planning to take a Utah tour in May that starts Monday morning from Grand Junction, Colorado. It sounds both more exciting and more economical to fly to Denver (from Boston)  Saturday and take the California Zephyr across Colorado on Sunday - the Boston to Grand Junction flight via Denver is much more  expensive than the flight to Denver plus the Amtrak ticket and I would be taking the extra travel day in any case.
I am concerned about how likely the Zephyr is to be significantly late (say, more than three hours from its scheduled 5:30 Grand Junction arrival).
In a pinch I could rent a car in Denver and drive across Colorado (four people in the car, which would defray the cost). But thinking ahead to that possibility suggests I wait to buy my Zephyr ticket until the day before. Is the train likely to be full?

I don't know about full, but from experience and anecdote it is very likely to be late.

In general long haul Amtrak passenger trains are never on time.  So I wouldn't want to rely on them for making a critical connection (to your tour in this case).    However, I do recommend that route.   So if you'd want to go, I'd take an extra day to absorb any delays.

Google gives a lot of results about poor punctuality, like this, and this question discusses how to get detailed Amtrak statistics (check out the link in the comment to the answer as the one in the answer is dead).

@NateEldredge but three hours late?

In my limited experience of Amtrak, 3 hours is not implausible. One scenario (that happened to me) is that the train ahead is running slow, reaches limit of crew's allowed working hours, no progress till a new crew can be brought in, possibly over a significant distance.

About eight years ago we had a Boston <-> Denver round trip.  Arrival in Denver on the outbound trip was 7-8 hours late.  (Anecdote, not summary, but confirming above comments that 3 hours late is not outside of possibility.)

@Midavalo: Yes, absolutely, or much more.

Though, if you're starting on Monday morning (presumably spending Sunday night in Grand Junction), you could afford to be several hours late, right?

@NateEldredge Yes, Monday morning start. I will speak with the tour organizer about possiblly missing the previous night's orientation.

I have a photo from the arrivals board in Boston's South Station that showed the expected arrival time for a train from Chicago to be 27 hours late (at time of photo).

Fully refundable tickets on Amtrak are IIRC not that much more expensive, so that could take care of concerns about the train selling out. On the other hand, your "rental car backup" strategy won't help in case the train leaves Denver on time, but is delayed en route. Such delays usually involve being stopped in some remote area where you can't get off, so switching to a rental car isn't an option.

@Midavalo  I can also attest to Amtrak trains being late.  And that 3 hours late is in the realms of possibility.

This link shows the delays on the westbound California Zephyr out of Denver for May 2023.  It shows 4 departures more than 3 hours late, plus another that was close, and more than half the departures were late.  Note that this can be highly seasonal and dependent on weather conditions in the entire stretch from Chicago to Denver.  I enjoy Amtrak and the Utah-Colorado part of that route is quite nice, but I absolutely would not depend on it if I needed to guarantee being somewhere on time.
